# Tool for scheduling Facebook messages

Tags: facebook

I would like to schedule Facebook messages. To be clear, I am talking about messages, not posts and Hootsuite, which I was recommended when I asked this question elsewhere, only allows scheduling of posts.

I am open to free or unpaid, but my main criteria is that the service should be supplied to a company that is as legitimate as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is the closest that you are going to get, but it is against their terms of service.

[facebook-chat-api NodeJS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-chat-api)

Another alternative is

[Quora Recommended Site FollowLike](http://www.followinglike.com/)

[Quora Page](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-schedule-message-in-Messenger/answer/Larry-Miller-128?srid=qd4U)

### [image: Quora Followlike]

Facebook also has automated bots that may interest you.

https://messenger.fb.com/

You will have to build on top of it, but it is possible.
[Facebook Bot](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#send_api_basics)

[image: Facebook Messenger Platform]